# zip inverse function in Python - Nested list having different length of sublist

Tags: python-2.7, list-comprehension

I'm trying to get expected result by using Zip inverse on a single list having sublist of unequal length. Just wondering if there is a way to achieve this through list comprehension.

```
    a = [[1,2],[1]]

    print zip(*a)

    result : 
    [(1, 1)]

    Expected result:
    [((1, 1)), ((2, None))]
```

Comment: [The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the **shortest argument sequence**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip). itertools has [`izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) for the behavior you want.

Comment: @dhke Yes, i'm aware of izip_longest() but i'm not sure if it can fit in this example.

Comment: @MSH `izip_longest(*a)` does **precisely** what you want. It really is worth both reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) and trying things out, you know.

Comment: Are those extra brackets in the expected result supposed to have a meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) stops when *one* of the sequences runs out, i.e. it only returns only as many items as the smallest sub sequences has elements.

> The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence

`itertools` have [`izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest), which runs over the longest sequences, returning a filler element for non-existing items:

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[1]]
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> print list(izip_longest(*a))
[(1, 1), (2, None)]
```